# react appjs triggering before useeffect router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

i have a problem how can i trigger my useeffect method in my appjs file before the router

first of all what can i do to have useeffect trigger in app js

Appjs File

```
import GlobalContext from "./context/globalContext";
import Routers from "./router/index"
function App() {
    const {initAuth} = useContext(GlobalContext)
    alert("appjs")
    useEffect(() => {
        alert("appJS Use Effect")
        initAuth()
    }, [])
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                <Routers/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default App;
```

My Router

```
export default function Routers() {
    alert("RoutersJS")
    useEffect(()=>{
        alert("useEffect RouterJS")
    },[])
    return (
        <Router>
             ....
       </Router>

    )
}
```

Comment: Use effect is more like componentdidmount and childs componentdidmount is called before parents one. It's react default nature. Why you want to achieve this and can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

Yousaf is correct that you cannot do this directly, or change the order of rendering. If there's a side-effect that absolutely must be sequenced correctly between the two elements, you could create a prop to router that tells it when it's allowed to make it's side-effect.

This introduces a lot of coupling between these elements, and I wouldn't recommend it unless you absolutely need these two elements to have a side-effect that must be sequenced.

```
function App() {
    ...
    const [hasAlerted, setHasAlerted] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        alert("appJS Use Effect");
        initAuth();
        setHasAlerted(true);
    }, [])
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
                <Routers canAlert={hasAlerted} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}


export default function Routers({canAlert})) {
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (canAlert) {
            alert("useEffect RouterJS")
        }
    },[canAlert])
    return (
        <Router>
             ....
       </Router>

    )
}
```

**Quick Explanation**

On the first render, `hasAlerted` will be false. The `App` will alert on after the first render. We will pass `canAlert=false` to the `Routers` component, so it will not alert on the first render.

Because we `setHasAlerted(true)` the tree will render again. On the 2nd render, `hasAlerted` will be true. The `App` will not alert, because it's useEffect dependencies have not changed. We will pass `canAlert=true` to the `Routers` component, so it will alert on the second render.

Again, I'd probably explore other solutions if you're able to.